# Como personalizar una fecha usando moment JavaScript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

estoy haciendo algunas mejoras visuales en mi proyecto y hasta el momento estoy usando `moment` de la siguiente manera `moment(operationData?.createdAt).format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A")` para mostrar la fecha de creacion de una operation. Pero quisiera mostrar esa fecha un poco mas personalizada donde me muestre si fue creada en el día de hoy me muestre a la hora que se realizo solamente, si fue creada en el dia anterior me muestre el dia de la semana y la hora, si fue creada en el mes me muestre el dia y la hora, si fue creada en el año me muestre el dia y el mes y si fue creada en el año entonces que me la muestre completa como lo hace este formato `moment(operationData?.createdAt).format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A")`. Estuve revisando `moment(operationData?.createdAt).fromNow()` pero esto solo me refleja el tiempo que ha transcurrido desde que se realizo!

Alguna idea de como poder implementar esto que necesito?

Comment: Si, con varias comprobaciones usando lo que hasta ahora has investigado. Una serie de `if ... else` sería la forma básica de lograrlo.

Comment: Tal cual, comparas cuanto tiempo ha transcurrido desde que se creo y segun eso, usando if...else lo formateas de una manera u otra usando el .format que ya usas

Comment: Si así lo hice. En breve pongo mi solución